# How to serialize data and preserve object references

Tags: serialization, frameworks, entity

I am using .NET 5. The object structure is as follows (example):

```
public partial class Teacher
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Student> Students { get; } = new();
}

public partial class Student 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Teacher> Teachers { get; } = new();
}
```

There is a N:N mapping table `TeacherStudent` only on the database side (no model class in Entity Framework).

In standard configuration this yields to a "possible object cycle detected"-Error because each entity is referencing the other. Serializing it, will create an endless loop.

There are several workarounds to suppress this behaviour. For example:
Adding `[JsonIgnore]` to the property which leads to the cycle.

Also it's possible to add

```
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            });
```

But I want to preserve the information in a way as that only the ID of the other entity is shown in my json object. For instance:

```
Teacher 0:
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "studentIds": [0, 1, 2, 3]
  }
]
Student 0: 
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "teacherIds": [0, 6, 14]
  }
]
```

I'm aware that it's possible to keep them kind of with the following action

```
JsonSerializerOptions options = new()
            {
                ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve,
                WriteIndented = true
            };
```

but this also adds metadata to my JSON object:

```
"$id": "0",
"Id": 0,
"Students": {
  "$id": "2",
  "$values": [...]
}
```

Does anyone know a way to only show the proper foreign key ids of the foreign entity?